# Run bash script after New WiFi connection

Tags: wifi, script

Noobs installation. I've a script which needs to be run after a new WiFi connection is set.
Is there any way to run this script automatically once we connect/set WiFi?

Answer (score 1):

You can run `wpa_cli -a /home/pi/script_to_run_on_connect.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

IFNAME=$1
CMD=$2

if [ "$CMD" = "CONNECTED" ]; then
    # do stuff on connect.
fi

if [ "$CMD" = "DISCONNECTED" ]; then
    # remove network configuration, if needed
fi
```

Comment: Hey Doug, will this script run automatically when we setup WiFi in GUI?

Comment: Don't know. My Raspberries run headless. Try it by writing something to syslog.